# How to set up CNAME for Heroku custom name

Tags: heroku-toolbelt

I have a small rails app set up on Heroku: tranquil-mountain-51138. I added a custom domain: 'johndcowan.com' and set up the CNAME record on my DNS Registrar per the tutorials.  I'm pretty sure I've done something incorrectly.

When I open up a browser and enter 'www.johndcowan.com', I see http://tranquil-mountain-51138.herokuapp.com/.  I was hoping to see www.johndcowan.com in the url bar.

I've followed a few tutorials, but the CNAME edit/change on my DNS registrar seems to be a bit different.

Heroku:

[image]

My CNAME edit on my dns registar.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Goto `heroku.com` select your app then goto `setting` and add domain

```
tranquil-mountain-51138 -> johndcowan.com
```

Comment: Thanks but, it wont let me add tranquil-mountain-51138.  I can add johndcowan.com but it ends up pointing to johndcowan.com.herokudns.com